# Ruby Bundle not running via cronjob

Tags: ruby, bash, bundle, cron

I'm trying to run a ruby bundle from a cronjob and it's not working, yet if I run the bundle from bash command-line, it works fine.  Am I missing something?

The command is:
`BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/client/Gemfile bundle exec /client/bin/runner`

I've set it in crontab as follows:
`*/1 * * * * BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/client/Gemfile bundle exec /client/bin/runner`

But am getting no results.  I really appreciate the help all!

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Under which user runs the cron job? Is it the same than the one in the console? What do you mean by *no results*, no even an error?

Comment: Yes, @spickermann the crontab is root and the bundle exec belongs to root as well.

Answer (score 0):

Little did I know rbenv was being used, so the fix is:

`*/1 * * * * bash -lc 'BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/client/Gemfile bundle exec /client/bin/runner'`